# Formal instruments to check properties of SQL queries

Tags: formal-methods

I have some operations defined as SQL queries which takes data from various tables combines it with the data from a base table and generates new rows, which are written back to the base table. In the words, a set of operations which populates base table with new data based on existing data.

In the process of testing I discovered that (i) in some situations two different operations A and B may generate duplicate rows, while (ii) in other situations the result of an operation C may be totally contained in the result of another operation D (i.e. all the new rows generated by C are generated by D too).

Thus I came to the following question: is there a math-like language in which I could easy translate my SQL queries and analyze their properties in order to discover analytically more properties than (i) and (ii) which I have discovered empirically?